# What does $D_{12}f$ mean compared to $D_{1}f$, for example?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative

What does $D_{12}f$ mean in the context of partial derivatives, with $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, for example? This is used in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

It is clear to me what that $D_1 f$ is the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$. Is $D_{12}f$ a row vector
$
\begin{bmatrix}
D_1f & D_2f
\end{bmatrix}
$?

Comment: My apologies, this is defined further in the book than I've read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, usually
$$
D_{12}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x\partial y}.
$$